# Windows 10 IoT Development in VS2017

Tags: windows, visual-studio, iot, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I am trying to build a basic GUI app for Windows 10 IoT Core. I'll run it on Raspberry Pi 3.

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 Community and Windows SDK 10.1.15063.137. When I am trying to make the app I am getting an error in VS 2017:

> Please update Windows 10 creator 10.0.15063.6 or later.

I have already running SDK 10.1.15063.137. Then why does this error appear? In my project property ... target version is "Windows 10 creators update (10.0, build 15063).

Comment: Are you also running the same (or later) version on your development machine and the IoT device? You only said you upgraded the SDK, not the OS.

Comment: When the error occurs, build on desktop or deploy to Raspberry Pi 3 ? What's the OS version of your desktop and Raspberry Pi ?

Comment: Hi.I am getting the error in my PC windows 10 when trying to open the VS2017 project MianPage.xaml file.

Below is the detail of all versions:

PC Windows 10 OS Version: 1607 (OS Build 14393.1198).
Windows 10 SDK Vrsion: 10.1.15063.137.
RPi3 Windows 10 IoT Version: 10.0.15063.0.

Can you please advice what I need to do to get this fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: You may need update your PC OS version to 15063. The same error is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64ef706d-601d-4f6d-8abc-83b2f5306421/uwpvisual-studio-requires-newer-version-of-windows-to-display-the-content-please-update-windows?forum=wpdevelop).